# give a permission to program to access a folder in windows server

Tags: java, windows, server, windows-server-2019, system-administration

I have a network of a local server and 3 pcs, and the server has a shared java program (.exe) and a shared folder. I need to make the 3 pcs to access the shared program and only this program can access the shared folder. this means only the shared program can access the folder.

Comment: Since Windows file protection is based on user identity, the straightforward way is to make the program on the server run under a dedicated account.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @user16632363 can I make the folder protection based on the program that tries to access the folder?

Comment: No.  Apart from any other reason (such as "there is no such feature"), the server would have no way to securely identify a program running on a different machine.